# Exception Unhandled : Could not load file or assembly 'Serilog.Extensions.Hosting,

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, serilog, filenotfoundexception

When I run my application, this exception is thrown even before the start of debugging.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoiQw.png)

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Serilog.Extensions.Hosting, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10'. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.'

This is my .csproj references :

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="3.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="7.0.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis" Version="2.6.122" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKS4g.png)

I tried to clean and build the entire solution and projects so many times also `dotnet restore`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

- Closing visual studio
- Deleting all bin and obj folders
- Reopen VS, restore nugets
- Clean and rebuild

Otherwise it may be that you need to install another netcore runtime.